# Make git push fail when there are uncommitted changes

Tags: git, git-push

I normally use something like the following to test my changes, and if they are ok, push them to the remote repository:

```
mvn install && git push
```

Works great except for that stupid user that has written beautiful code, but forgot to commit it /*facepalm*/

Is there a way to make git push fail when there are uncommitted changes? Or maybe a separate command that checks for uncommitted changes, so I get something like this:

```
mvn install && git --clean-only push
```

or

```
mvn install && git is-clean && git push
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably use `mvn install && git diff --quiet --cached && git push`. This checks for *uncommitted* changes. If you'd like to check for *unstaged* changes, use `git diff --quiet` instead (or both).

Comment: Or `git status --porcelain` gives an overview of the actual files not staged or staged but not committed.

Comment: And, add this as a pre-push hook and never worry about it again.

Comment: @martin I don't like the hook based solution, because it is something I want often, but not always. At least for me. A separate command/alias works better.

Comment: @PatrickB. But that always returns 0 so I can't use it easily in the command chain. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JensSchauder `VAR=\`git status --porcelain | wc -l\``